# How to get from dev tools in chrome- network tab,

Tags: javascript, java

I  want to filter by collect?v=1 in network tab in dev console, in chrome to filter the data from datalayer to access the **analytics tags**

Comment: There is a Filter Bar you can Filter Network requests.

Comment: Hi @vidhya, is your question about [javascript], [java] or [google-chrome]?